# Applying Quantile Buckets to Rows

Tags: r

My objective is to establish quantiles for a given column and then assign to each row the appropriate bucket based on these quintiles.

Determining the quintile data is easy enough:

```
quantile(df$x, probs=seq(0,1,0.2),na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I'm a little lost as to how to assign this information to each row using functions instead of manually hashing it all out. I've played around using `apply` and `tapply` but haven't quite gotten there. Something like this just results in essentially the same information as above but references specific UIDs and additional columns in the bucketing:

```
apply(df, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: If it is `rows`, then use `MARGIN=1` instead of `2`

Comment: A small example data set, for example `data(WorldPhones)`, and a demonstration of your expected outcome, would really help us in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, using the iris sample data:

```
q <- quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, probs=seq(0,1,0.2),na.rm = TRUE)
```

gets the quintiles.  Then you could use `cut` to assign observations to buckets.

```
iris$qc <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, q)
table(iris$qc)
```

Gives you

```
    (4.3,5]    (5,5.6]  (5.6,6.1] (6.1,6.52] (6.52,7.9] 
         31         33         30         25         30
```

Which I think is what you want.  You could change the names if you wanted, also play around with the options.

Comment: Not quite what I want. 

Right now I have a table with two columns, a UID and some variable. What I ultimately want is a third column that indicates the quantile of said variable appended to the original table.

Comment: So in that case wouldn't you assign the result to a column in the data frame? E.g. `iris$newcolumn`? Also do you want quantiles or quintiles?

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, yes. And ultimately I'm going to put them in quintiles but I said quantiles to keep things open to any # of buckets

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: So close. However, the field it creates is just the range of the quintile instead of the bucket #. So for instance, if bucket 2 ranges from (20-100], it just prints (20-100] in said column.

Comment: Looks like all I needed was labels = FALSE on the bucketing. Thanks a million!